# Howto pass vars from before_filter to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering how to pass @current_day and @has_day to my view?

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :detect_current_day

  def index
    #some logic
  end

 private

 def detect_current_day
    if (params[:year] && params[:month] && params[:day])
      @current_day =  Date.parse params.values_at(:year, :month, :day).join('.')
    else
      @current_day = Date.today;
    end

    # Check if day already exist
    @hasToday = Post.created_on(@current_day).count > 0 ? true : false;
  end

end
```

Thanks

Comment: There should not be anything more that you already did: you set instance variables and that's enough. What's your error?

Comment: Note that you've got a typo somewhere. Your question mentions `@has_day` but your code shows `@hasToday`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have done correctly but you are expecting wrong instance variables. you defined @current_day and @hasToday. you will get it in view.if you want @has_day.please initialize in your before filter

```
@has_day = Post.created_on(@current_day).count > 0 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but your @current_day is in date format, and if you want to print it out in your view you need to convert it to:

```
<%= @current_day.strftime("%Y %m %d") %>
```